# Save data using Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey for later retrieval

Tags: javascript, html, database, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am working on a project which requires data from a website. The problem with that data is that it is organised into a lot of different webpages with serial numbering in the URL. To tackle this problem, I wrote a simple script in Tampermonkey which loops through those pages and obtains the data in a string variable in the script.

Now comes the real problem, how do I store this data. I know I can't write to a file on my PC but can the data be displayed onto a separate tab in my browser so that I can copy and paste it into a local file when the loop is done? I wish to append a string into storage each loop

I do not want to use `GM_setValue` because I want the data in raw text format (like a `.txt` file)

However, if it can be written directly into a file on my PC without the use of an external library, that'd be preferred.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I know I can't write to a file on my PC

Here's some good news for you: Yes you can!

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "data:text,Hello World!";   //content
a.download = "Hello.txt";            //file name
a.click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/jgfhwfL0/

---

First open up your localhost page, `master.html` (`http://localhost:8080/master.html`):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("load", function(){
                //This is just like working with threads but in JavaScript
                if(location.search.length){
                    //receiver
                    var query = decodeURIComponent(location.search.slice(1));
                    var data = JSON.parse(query).value;

                    //handle data
                    localStorage.storage = +localStorage.storage + data;

                    location.href = "about:blank";  //exit
                }else{
                    //master
                    sum = document.getElementById("sum"); 
                    sum.innerText = localStorage.storage = "0";

                    window.addEventListener("storage", function(){
                        //data received from receiver
                        sum.innerText = localStorage.storage;
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Sum: <span id="sum"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you can start sending data to it in any webpages:

```
var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
frame.src = 'http://localhost:8080/master.html?{"value":90}';    //port 8080
document.body.appendChild(frame);
```

The sum counter should update automatically upon receiving data.

Comment: Assuming this is all standard JS. Let's say I already have a text file stored on my PC, will I be able to edit it using JS/Tampermonkey to append data?

Comment: Yes, HTML5 have a [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) which lets you read files. Note that you as a user will have to pick the file through the browser UI (a file picker modal) instead of the program opening it automatically because of security reasons.

Comment: Well that's the problem. I have 100+ webpages which I want to obtain data from and store it on a local file. I don't need to read it using JS but only edit and create it.

Comment: @AvZ Have you considered creating an extension instead of using Tampermonkey which can only inject scripts into webpages? An extension has much more permissions and will make this way easier.

Comment: I only want to use TM/GM to somehow keep the information. It'd be fine with me each string is appended to a webpage displayed in the tab of my browser which I can then copy and paste to a text file

Comment: Even if it's stored in the log of TM somehow, at least it can be copy-pasted

Comment: @AvZ If the file is initially blank, one way I can think of is to create a master webpage hosted on localhost and send all the data to there which you can collect the data at the end (presumably write them to a file.)

Comment: How would I do that? Can you show it in the answer?

Comment: I get a SERVER_BAD_CONTENT when trying to download scraped content from a site (not localhost), any way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is running a localhost HTTP server, exposing routes and using them to read and write files and generally do all of the back-end things you need for your userscript(s).

Here's a simple proof of concept echo using Node 17 and Express, but the same can be done with any back-end technology that you prefer.

`server.js`:

```js
const cors = require("cors"); // "^2.8.5"
const express = require("express"); // "^4.18.1"
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const path = require("path");

const dataFile = "data.json";
const app = express();
app
  .set("port", process.env.PORT || 5000)
  .use(cors())
  .use(express.json())
  .get("/", (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, dataFile))
      .then(file => res.send(file.toString()))
      .catch(err => res.status(404).send(err.message));
  })
  .post("/", (req, res) => {
    const p = path.join(__dirname, dataFile);
    fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(req.body))
      .then(file => res.sendStatus(200))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err.message));
  })
  .listen(app.get("port"), () =>
    console.log(`server listening on port ${app.get("port")}`)
  );
```

Tampermonkey script:

```js
const url = "http://localhost:5000";

const writeData = payload =>
  fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.status);
      }
    });

const readData = () =>
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.status);
      }
    
      return response.json();
    });

writeData({hello: "world"})
  .then(readData)
  .then(data => console.log(data)) // => {hello: 'world'}
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

There's nothing special here other than enabling cross-origin access and the novelty of sending requests from a userscript rather than a typical client such as a webpage or app.

Use caution since this exposes the local file system to potentially malicious scripts running on an unknown website.